# How do I get the Status with TimestampCreate that match ControlPoint Timestamp?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I would like like to get the Status whose TimestampCreate match the ControlPoint Timestamp. **The match do not have to match milliseconds**

I am not sure how to do it.

**I am using xslt 1.0**
**Expected output**

```
<ProtectionOrderStatus>
    <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>SBJO</ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
    <ProtectionOrderStatusDate>2016-05-09</ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
</ProtectionOrderStatus>
```

**My xml 1.0 code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Integration>
    <ControlPoint Timestamp="5/9/2016 2:34:34 PM" UserID="Kuku">SAVE</ControlPoint>
    <ProtectionOrders>
        <ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="11831">
            <Statuses>
                <Status>
                    <Current>true</Current>
                    <Active>No</Active>
                    <Date>05/09/2016</Date>
                    <Type Word="DISMISSED">Dismissed</Type>
                    <TimestampCreate Op="A">05/09/2016 14:34:48:633</TimestampCreate>
                </Status>
                <Status Op="A">
                    <Current>false</Current>
                    <Active>Yes</Active>
                    <Date Op="A">05/09/2016</Date>
                    <Type Op="A" Word="SBJO">Signed By Judicial Officer</Type>
                    <TimestampCreate>05/09/2016 14:34:34:737</TimestampCreate>
                </Status>
                <Status>
                    <Current>false</Current>
                    <Active>No</Active>
                    <Date>12/30/2014</Date>
                    <Type Word="DRAFT">Draft</Type>
                    <TimestampCreate>05/09/2016 14:34:14:987</TimestampCreate>
                </Status>
            </Statuses>
        </ProtectionOrder>
    </ProtectionOrders>
</Integration>
```

**My xslt code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ProtectionOrderStatus>
    <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
        <xsl:value-of select="Statuses/Status/Type/@Word"/>
    </ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
    <ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="Statuses/Status/Date"/>
    </ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
</ProtectionOrderStatus>
```

My xslt is producing the following output which is wrong

```
        <ProtectionOrderStatus>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>DISMISSED</ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusDate>2016-05-09</ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
    </ProtectionOrderStatus>
```

Comment: You are using some non-standard extension functions: it's hard to say how they should be used without knowing which XSLT processor you are using. -- Also, if by "match" you mean "match to the nearest second", you should state so explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="ctl" select="Integration/ControlPoint/@Timestamp"/>
<xsl:variable name="date" select="substring-before($ctl, ' ')"/>
<xsl:variable name="time" select="substring-before(substring-after($ctl, ' '), ' ')"/>

<xsl:variable name="month" select="substring-before($date, '/')"/>  
<xsl:variable name="day" select="substring-before(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')"/>
<xsl:variable name="year" select="substring-after(substring-after($date, '/'), '/')"/>

<xsl:variable name="h12" select="substring-before($time, ':')"/>
<xsl:variable name="pm" select="contains($ctl,'PM')"/>
<xsl:variable name="h" select="$h12 mod 12 + 12 * $pm"/>

<xsl:variable name="ts">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($month, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($day, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$h"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($time, ':')"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="status" select="//Status[starts-with(TimestampCreate, $ts)]"/>
    <ProtectionOrderStatus>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
            <xsl:value-of select="$status/Type/@Word"/>
        </ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
        <ProtectionOrderStatusDate>     
            <xsl:value-of select="$status/Date"/>
        </ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
    </ProtectionOrderStatus>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProtectionOrderStatus>
   <ProtectionOrderStatusCode>SBJO</ProtectionOrderStatusCode>
   <ProtectionOrderStatusDate>05/09/2016</ProtectionOrderStatusDate>
</ProtectionOrderStatus>
```

**Note**:

- This assumes that the hour in `TimestampCreate` is **not** zero-padded to double-digits (your example is ambiguous in this respect);
- If more than one `Status` matches the condition, only the first one's values will be returned.

Comment: Awesome Michael. Using your solution my code is now returning the correct output. There is not be  more than one status with the same timestampcreate.

Comment: I have a question for you Michael.hor257k. My code is working after using your code. However my boss asked me to use internal functions we have in a stylesheet. Since I might lose points if I edit the question, what would you recommend doing? Should I edit the question or should I post a new question where I can include the stylesheet with the functions I am supposed to call to convert the TimestampCreate and TimeStamp? Please advise.

Comment: I would suggest you post a new question - and make sure we understand what those functions are and what exactly do they do. Although I suspect you won't be able to use them on the dates in your input.

Comment: I will post a new question. I will add the stylesheet with the functions I am supposed to call. Thank you again for your advise.